# Solving security bugs in “Writing Secure Code” '

Tags: c, security

I'm studying code security and I'm trying to do a security analysis on the following 2 snippets, taken from “Writing Secure Code”, 2nd Edition:

http://www.di.uniba.it/~ndm/corsi/sa/materiale/lab/StackOverrun.c

http://www.di.uniba.it/~ndm/corsi/sa/materiale/lab/FormatString.c

In the first one I think the only non-secure statement is 
    `strcpy(buf, input);`
which should be
    `strncpy(buf, input, sizeof(buf-1));`
All the other printf are secure: even though they are using less arguments than they shoud they are doing it on purpose.

In the second one again the `printf`s are secure but the `fprintf(stdout, buf);` is not and should be replaced with this code: `fprintf(stdout, "%s", buf);`

My problem is that `pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");` is also considered unsecure by analysis programs due to a possible race condition but I can see no way this can be exploited in this code. If the file is opening for read-only can the attacker do something nasty with it? I think no.

So the question is: do you think this analysis is correct? Can you find other flaws or is my reasoning bugged?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean here: http://www.di.uniba.it/~ndm/corsi/sa/materiale/lab/FormatString.c ?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I don't know why it didn't show up!

Comment: `strncpy(buf, input, sizeof(buf-1));` is still wrong, since it does not nul-terminate the destination if the source is too long.

Comment: @Steve you're right. I'll add buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = "\0"; after it

Comment: There's also a typo: it's sizeof(buf)-1 not sizeof(buf-1). Damn, security checking is hard.

Comment: ugh, sizeof()? Don't do buffers on the stack, do them on the heap :)

Comment: @Steve: But `strncpy()` is still wrong unless the destination requires nul-padding if the source is shorter, too. If using C strings, `strcpy()` is absolutely the right function to copy them, and is not "non-secure" in itself - "non-secure"-ness comes from not preparing the destination (i.e. not making it big enough).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that it's bad to pass non-sanitized program input into libc calls. There was just too many cases where libc would overflow, and developers should not pass arguments that exceed expectations of the libc (like the string should be < PATH_MAX in this case).

But since you mentioned race condition, I think that though in this particular instance there is no particular problem, use of fopen() is frowned upon in general, as it is prone to race conditions. If you are addressing a file, any file, using functions that take in file name rather than file handles. If you refer to a file by its path name, with one operation, or another, the state of a file can change, and program's assumption about that state may no longer be correct. It's better explained in the below articles.

http://www.sans.edu/research/security-laboratory/article/race-cndtns

http://www.unixprogramming.info/s_isregfile-race-conditions

Comment: Can an attacker use that fopen with symbolic links to get to know, for example, if some file he has no right to access exists?

Comment: As an example, certainly. If the program just cats the file to the stdout, attacker can read /etc/shadow, for example, which is sorta bad, but then there are all them private keys that can be read, and so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Development site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html) comes this clear description:

if you open a file and then read from it, even though your application did nothing else between these two operations, some other process might alter the file after the file was opened and before it was read. If two different processes (in the same or different applications) were writing to the same file, there would be no way to know which one would write first and which would overwrite the data written by the other. Such situations cause security vulnerabilities.

There are two basic types of race condition that can be exploited: time of check–time of use (TOCTOU), and signal handling.

Furthermore, the fopen() call as shown **is not doing any sanitization of the filename**. Of course you wouldn't really do that, right? The name absolutely should be analyzed, examined and **simply not be trusted** since it's a argument to the program. Ideally you should [use more than a single attribute to identify a file](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/FIO05-CPP.+Identify+files+using+multiple+file+attributes)